# Add values in C# list using class dto

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I have below code. In that I am getting companies and then I am adding that companies to new List based on dto class.

```
 var companies = new List<Company>();
 companies = await _companyRepo.GetCompaniesByUserId(CurrentUserId);

                if (companies != null)
                {
                    var companyL = companies.Select(c => new CompanyDTO()
                    {
                        CompanyId = c.Id,
                        CompanyName = c.CompanyName,
                        Priority = c.Priority.ToString()
                }).ToList();
```

Now I am getting one more value of Date field but to get that I need to call await method so I am getting that value in this way.

```
var Logindate = await _companyRepo.GetLoginDate(company.Id);
```

So now I want to add this value in above companyL list for each company.. I tried in this way but it' not working.

```
companyL = companies.Select(c => new CompanyDTO()
                    {
                        Logindate = c.LoginDate
                    }).ToList();
```

Any idea on this..

Comment: The function you use in select can be async just add the specifier like `async c => ...` and then you can do awaitable stuff in the func.

Comment: @Ralf You shouldn't just add the async modifier without understanding how it fits in. If the Select extension method isn't set up to run async functions, this won't even compile. See [this Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/42BDyY) for an example.

Comment: Have your tried `async c=> new CompanyDTO(){....Logindate = await _companyRepo.GetLoginDate(company.Id) }` in your code?

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework, Dapper or ADO? EFCore has a feature to fetch data using select and you could get both of that in one command (executing two requests inside database) but returning just one thing and without the need to await twice.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to call the second method!

You can do this :

```
var companies = new List<Company>();
companies = await _companyRepo.GetCompaniesByUserId(CurrentUserId);

                if (companies != null)
                {
                    var companyL = companies.Select(c => new CompanyDTO()
                    {
                        CompanyId = c.Id,
                        CompanyName = c.CompanyName,
                        Priority = c.Priority.ToString(),
                        Logindate = c.LoginDate
                }).ToList();
```

Just it!